# convert webm audio to ogg in flutter to send via whatsapp api

Tags: flutter, dart, whatsapp-cloud-api

I would like to know how I can convert a base64 audio file with webm format to ogg format because I want to send an audio via the WhatsApp api and it requires these formats:
audio/aac, audio/mp4, audio/mpeg, audio/amr, audio/ogg
Because the format is not compatible, I cannot send it.
In my case, I can't send the file to WhatsApp media because I don't have the path, I only have the bytes that I convert to base64.
Would anyone know how I can solve this problem please?

I tried to use a converter on the web and change the format but unfortunately I was unsuccessful.